Complete lattices where elements have an orientation
Is there a known concept of complete lattices where there is not only a partial order between the elements, but the individual elements themselves also have a kind of "orientation"? Something in the spirit that elements can be oriented up or down or neutral (or neither).
Sorry for the kind of fuzzy question. I am currently exploring such a concept and don't know (yet) how to express this better.

Can you give us a little more on what it would mean for an element to be oriented?

I currently think of it as an additional property that the elements have. Like a sequence (considered as one object), for instance, can be ascending (up), descending (down), constant (neutral), or - say - "oscillating" (neither).

I guess the most natural way to start is to simply think of orientation of an object in a lattice (or any other set-based object) is simply as an assignment of objects to their orientations i.e. a function  o:L-->O from a lattice L to a set of possible orientations O. I guess the natural next question is how orientations and the lattice operations interact. For example, does the orientation of the join of x and y depend on the orientation of x and the orientation of y?

As an answer to your actual question, I'm not aware of any known concept that conforms to what you've suggested.

Yes, I think in my case, at least binary joins and meets would preserve the orientation. For example, the join of two up-oriented elements is also up-oriented.

sounds to me like the Issing model is made
